# How can i extract a specific part of string in oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have some records with a column name "text_note". Now i need to find out that which text_note contains  a string like `%CTOE0%`.

I think it can be done using regular expressions,but since i'm not that much familiar
with regular expressions, i'm not able to create a regular expression for it.

Please help.
FORGOT TO MENTION
i WANT THE CODE(CTOE) PART IN A DIFFERENT COULMN

my issue is that i just don't wanna show 'CTOE' in next column.I want to know what code is used. the types of code that can be used are CTOE01,CTOE02,CTOE03 AND SO ON.Now i wanna know which of these codes have been used.

The example is as follows: if the text not contains "dsghdsCTOE01dbhf" then new column should contain "CTOE01" if the text not contains "dsCTOE02dbhf" then new column should contain "CTOE02" –

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `regexp_substr` for that:

```
CREATE TABLE t (text_note VARCHAR2(30));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('dsghdsCTOE01dbhf');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('dsCTOE02dbhf');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('soemthingelse');

SELECT text_note, 
       regexp_substr(text_note, 'CTOE[0-9]+') AS code 
  FROM t
 WHERE   regexp_like(text_note, 'CTOE[0-9]+');


text_note         code
----------------  ----
dsghdsCTOE01dbhf  CTOE01
dsCTOE02dbhf      CTOE02
```

The `regexp_substr` extracts your new column, and the `regexp_like` filters rows that contain `CTOE...`.

Comment: I agree with your reg expression (the parenthesis though do not add any value for this requirement), but you do not have a filter to find the like 'CTOE[0-9]+' records.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the field starts and ends with a `%` and only contains upper-case letters and digits:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(text_note, '^%[A-Z0-9]+%$', 'c');
```

Comment: hOW CAN I SEPARATELY SHOW THE "ctoe" PART IN A DIFFERENT COLUMN SIDE BY SIDE??

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT text_note, 
substr(text_note, (instr(text_note, 'CTOE0')), 6)   AS CODE
FROM table where text_note like '%CTOE0%';
```

In above query, I assume that your code will be just 6 characters long and using substr function to capture the 6 character code. The ouptut required is got with above query.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Check out if this would help you!

```
Select text_note, 'CTOE' CODE from table
where text_note like '%\%CTOE0\%%;
```

I assume that % is also a part of your search string and trying to escape percentage as given [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_special_characters_like_sql_query.htm)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but my issue is that i just don't wanna  show 'CTOE' in next column.I want to know what code is used. the types of code that can be used are CTOE01,CTOE02,CTOE03 AND SO ON.Now i wanna know which of these codes have been used.

Comment: @user3146332: Then what would you like to show. Please edit your question with sample output and leave a comment below this one.

Comment: OK but what does text_note contain? Would it not be the same?

Comment: The example is as follows:
if the text not contains "dsghdsCTOE01dbhf" then new column should contain "CTOE01"
if the text not contains "dsCTOE02dbhf" then new column should contain "CTOE02"